# About connection between divisibility and roots of real polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

For complex polynomials of many variables the following theorem holds:

If $p(x_1,...,x_n), q(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb K[x_1,...,x_n]$, where $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$, are polynomials such that $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ is irreducible and for all $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb K$
$$
p(a_1,...,a_n)=0 \Rightarrow q(a_1,...,a_n)=0, 
$$
then $p(x_1,...,x_n) | q(x_1,...,x_n)$.

I look for a counterpart of this theorem in the case $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ for polynomials of the second order. 
Some additional assumptions are necessary, because for example for $p(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2^2$ and $q(x_1,x_2)=2x_1^2+x_2$ the above theorem is not true.

Is it  maybe true under additional assumption that $p,q$ are the second order and  that

there exists a $y=(y_1,...y_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $p(y)=0,  grad f(y)\neq 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If there is $y\in\mathbf R^n$ such that $p(y)=0$ and $\mathop{grad} p(y)\neq0$ then the set $\{p=0\}$ is a smooth real hypersurface of $\mathbf R^n$ in a neighborhood of the point $y$. This implies that $\{p=0\}$ is Zariski dense in the set $\{z\in\mathbf C^n\mid p(z)=0\}$. Hence, if $q$ vanishes on the real zero set $\{p=0\}$, it also vanishes on the complex zero set of $p$. It also implies that $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbf C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Therefore, $p$ divides $q$ in $\mathbf C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and hence in $\mathbf R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

Note that the conditions on the degree of $p$ and $q$ are superfluous.

Comment: Hi, I am interested by the result you mention, the fact that the real points of $\{p=0\}$ are Zariski dense in the complex points of $\{p=0\}$,  but have difficulty to locate a proof in the literature (I am not an expert on this subject). Could you possibly provide a reference with a proof ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @user111 I don't know for a reference and I was typing a proof as a comment, but it would be much nicer if you just ask the question as a new question so that I, or somebody else, can write a neat answer to it!

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331182/polynomials-or-analytic-functions-vanishing-on-a-real-algebraic-set)